# query regarding jquery.ui.spinner : event not getting raised

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using 'ui-spinner' with jquery version 'jquery-ui-1.10.4.js'

There is a button the visibility of which depends upon the ui-spinner.
I can set the visibility by raising onchange/keypress/keydown events on ui-spinner, but this is working only when the spinner arrows are being used. If I enter any digit through keyboard within ui-spinner the button visibility is not getting updated as none of the event is getting raised in this scenario.
The event will raise only when I click anywhere else on the screen after entering a number within ui-spinner textbox, but I need event to be raised the moment when I enter the number within ui-spinner textbox.

Below is the UI:
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfKNE.png)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>spinner demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    
    <input id="spinner" onkeyup="ShowMessage(this.value)" />
    <input type="button" id="btnHitMe" value="Hit Me !" disabled />
    <label id="UpdateValue">ddd</label>

    <script>
        $("#spinner").spinner();
        function ShowMessage(value) {
            
                
            $("#btnHitMe").prop('disabled', !(value.length > 0));
            
            console.log(value);
            $("#UpdateValue").text(value.length);
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some details to cover your answer explanation!